# Importing JS file with AJAX does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I had some JavaScript code which was working but when I tried to put it into its own file, it stopped working :)

Here is the url I use:
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/javascript_library.js

Any idea why now it doesn't work?  To test that it is working, try hitting this url to see if the google map shows up like it would if the JS was on the page.
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hike_carpool.php?hike_id=125

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"> 
    </script>   

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="javascript_library.js"> </SCRIPT>
```

place the google map api before your javascript_library.js (aka your map scripts)

and remove the script tag from your javascript_library.js

Answer (score 2):

Don't put HTML into your JavaScript files.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

↑ *Bad!*